# Is there way to fetch queries with Hibernate session.get()?

Tags: java, hibernate, fetch

I am working with Hibernate 5 Criteria Builder Queries fetching with Criteria Queries. But when calling session.get() SQL creating ***multiple queries*** for related Hibernate entities when calling them. Is there way to fetch them with one query as Hibernate Criteria Query Fetching.

```
CriteriaQuery<AdvanceRecieved> advanceCriteria = builder.createQuery(AdvanceRecieved.class);
Root<AdvanceRecieved> advanceRoot = advanceCriteria.from(AdvanceRecieved.class);

advanceRoot.fetch(AdvanceRecieved_.department,JoinType.LEFT);
```

I fetched these entities with fetch(), **But I haven't find an example for fetch below code example**.

```
ItemsABS selectedItem = jpaSess.get(ItemsABS.class, dealer.id);
Set<Tax> itemtaxes = selectedItem.getTaxEligibility();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing multiple queries because you probably have a One-To-Many relation between `ItemsABS` and `TAX` entities. So when you request `ItemsABS` data, it by default fetches the attached references (i.e. `TAX` data), and hence multiple queries are fired for that.

If you just need `ItemsABS` data, then you probably would have to use `LAZY LOADING` while fetching data for `ItemsABS`.
This can be defined at entity level using `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there way to fetch them with one query without hitting another query for get `Tax` data, like Fetch join ?

Comment: I don't think there would be using criteria or HQL. you can probably do that using Native SQL queries without having to map it with your Entities(which you would have to do using RowMapper explicitly).